# Is the Targaryen banner in S08E06 with four legs a new one?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The Targaryen banner in S08E06 had a dragon with 4 legs. This is contrary to the official Targaryen sigil.

Have we seen seen this banner before? Or is it the first time?

Comment: A similar banner was seen in Meereen atop the pyramid but as you say, it has two legs, not 4. In ASOIAF, Dragons do not have forelegs, they only have two hind legs, which makes them awkward at ground.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I'm aware the banner we see at the Red Keep in the final episode is a "new" version or just a mistake by the show in the later seasons. It appears to have been first introduced in the show when Dany and her fleet sail to Westeros in the final episode of Season 6 but does appear in the supporting material before that too. I'd still lean towards it being a mistake but this does mean it could be Dany's personal sigil or she updated it when she decided to head to Westeros for some unknown reason.

[image: Targaryen banner at the Red Keep]

The banner is also the four legged version previously in Season 8 when we see Euron ambush Dany's fleet at Dragonstone in Season 8 Episode 4, "The Last of the Starks".

[image: Dany's fleet showing the "new" sigil]

And again when Dany sails to Westeros from Essos in Season 6 Episode 10, "Winds of Winter", the sails appear to display the four legged version.

[image: Dany's fleet sailing to Westeros]

The other times we see the Targaryen sigil, it is the correct version where the dragon has two legs and not four. For example, the Banner in Meereen and the sigil on the Knightsguard at the Tower of Joy.

[image: Targaryen banner at Meereen] [image: Targaryen sigil on the Knightsguard]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

The sigil also appears various times in the *Histories & Lore* videos but each time has two legs. For example, in the Season 7 one for ["The Hand of the King"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMrFu.jpg). Except for in the Season 1 *Complete Guide to Westeros* feature on "House Targaryen" which shows it twice and both times it has four legs. However, they weren't sure if they were getting another season when they did the first one and hadn't seen the dragons properly yet so again this is probably just a mistake.

[image: House Targaryen video showing the sigil with four legs]

I'm not sure if it appears anywhere else but I don't think it does, as such we can conclude that this "new" banner is a new one for some reason but the message is lost on us or that the show made a mistake.

In fact the show has made this mistake for various out of universe items they have been selling over the years. When looking around I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/19wh0x/spoilers_alltargaryen_sigil_2_legs_or_4_legs/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) from 6 years ago that is questioning what the official sigil is because they bought what appears to be a HBO licensed keychain where the sigil is the same as the one at the Red Keep.

[image: Targaryen sigil keychain]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

As mentioned by other users the "new" sigil actually makes no sense as dragons in *Game of Thrones* and *A Song of Ice and Fire* have two hindlegs and two forearm wing "legs" so it has two legs on it that come from nowhere. You can clearly see Drogon in the first image proving that the "new" sigil is wrong... that's why he's screaming in anger, he just saw it.

We could argue that it might be Dany's personal sigil rather than her using the Targaryen one at the Red Keep but I find it unlikely.

Comment: I'm trying to find if there is a reason for the change but turned up nothing so far.

Comment: Four legs good... two legs baaad?

Answer (score 2):

As [Aegon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/54887/aegon) has stated, it was shown in Meereen once before, but that sigil had 2 legs, not four.

Additionally, the dragons that Daenerys has all only have 2 hindlegs, and wings, which match the sigil. This sigil shown in the final episode really makes very little sense, in the show. If it meant to represent something, it's unclear, and if it's not a mistake, then that's unclear as well.

Comment: FWIW the four legged version has shown up before, as early as Season 6 Episode 10.

Comment: What if it's meant to signify there are only 2 Targeryens left, Daenerys and Jon/Aegon? Keeping it in the family and all...